# How to check whether a JavaScript is active or not via PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Is it possible to do checking and verification of JavaScript state in a browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your index.php you could do something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = '/index_with_js.php'
</script>
```

So, if the browser had JS enabled, it would be redirected to a special index page, which could in turn set a session variable, e.g. `$_SESSION['has_js'] = true;`

If the browser doesn't have JS enabled, the page won't be directed, so `$_SESSION['has_js']` won't ever be set.

Answer (score 3):

No, not reliably. But it is possible to respond with something (on the client) if Javascript is not available using [noscript](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_noscript.asp):

```
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
```

Answer (score 3):

That's the wrong way to do it. PHP should be outputting markup that works with JavaScript off, and you should be enhancing that markup with JavaScript. I suggest you read up on [progressive enhancement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/).

Comment: More on that subject: http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you need to do this via PHP, instead of displaying a message in the browser using the [NOSCRIPT](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.1) tag?

Comment: yes, i need them to be one of basic condition how to display template and its feature. All html code that will be include into a php page (for example, index.php) based on the state of javascript